# Chrome Browser Cast extension supersedes Cactool Cast button

Tags: google-cast

I am trying to follow the tutorial here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-receiver/#4
But cactool cast won't work (step 3 of the tuto)

When I click Cast button at the top left, then Chrome's cast extension supersedes and takes control. Which means I can only cast the current tab on the device. So I cannot continue following steps that should allow me to select a file to cast...

I've tried using cactool on another browser (edge...sorry all I had installed) but the cast icon doesn't even show.

Any idea how to disable momentarily the integrated cast system in Chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

IT seems after a full PC restart and then forcing to cast from youtube a video, then cactool started working as intended and not casting the full browser tab anymore. Don't know what causes this, but at least I got a workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem but your workaround didn't fix it for me. When you say "forcing to cast from a youtube a video", you just mean you went to youtube.com, clicked the cast icon, and made the video (not the youtube site tab) cast, then disconnected the youtube cast session, and then it worked?